# drupal file_check_path return false

Tags: php, file, drupal-6, file-copying

I am working on files in drupal. i use local wamp server with drupal6.
my drupal path is `localhost/drupal6` .i have a file in this path `<drupal root >\files\images\111.jpg` .

`$image='/drupal6/files/images/111.jpg'`;

I want copy(or move) this file to another sub folder in this path but give me error in php `copy($image,'anotherdestination')` or `drupal_copy($image,'anotherdestination',FILE_EXISTS_RENAME)`.

when i use `var_dump(file_check_path($image));` it return me ***false*** . 
the `files` and `iamges` folder have all permission for any user in windows.
where is the problem?

***notice:*** i wrote all of this code in a function in a custom module  with path `sites/all/module/mymodule/mymodule.module`

Comment: i also use `var_dump($image);
  var_dump((file_create_path($image)));
  var_dump((file_check_location($image)));`  but all of them return false or 0 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between how files are accessed over HTTP and via the file system. Over web `/drupal6/files/images/111.jpg` is perfectly fine, since it'll be evaluated as `http://example.com/drupal6/files/images/111.jpg`. But I bet you do not have a `drupal6` directory in the root of your file system.

You probably want something like this.

```
copy('c:\drupal6\files\images\111.jpg', 'c:\drupal6\files\other_images\111.jpg');
```

I'm not entirely sure about paths in Windows but I think that should be correct.

Comment: tnx for your answer.you right about difference between file accessing  over HTTP and via the file system..but don't forget this website in future will upload to linux based server.i myself find out a solution for my problem yesterday.however tnx for your answer.

Comment: I should have mentioned it was meant to illustrate the difference. In your code you probably want to use `DRUPAL_ROOT` or the D6 equivalent. Thanks for the upvote!